# Oreo issue with settings Preferences in the app

Tags: java, android

I've written a setting code in the Android studio with Preferences and it works normally with all the Android versions instead of Android 8.0 Oreo. The error is:
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x102036d (android:id/prefs) for fragment GeneralPreferenceFragment. Does anyone have any idea why this version has a problem with the preferences? 
My setting activity is:

```
private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
        String stringValue = value.toString();

        if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
            // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
            // the preference's 'entries' list.
            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
            int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);

            // Set the summary to reflect the new value.
            preference.setSummary(
                    index >= 0
                            ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                            : null);

        } else if (preference instanceof RingtonePreference) {
            // For ringtone preferences, look up the correct display value
            // using RingtoneManager.
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(stringValue)) {
                // Empty values correspond to 'silent' (no ringtone).
                preference.setSummary(R.string.notification_is_silent);

            } else {
                Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
                        preference.getContext(), Uri.parse(stringValue));

                if (ringtone == null) {
                    // Clear the summary if there was a lookup error.
                    preference.setSummary(null);
                } else {
                    // Set the summary to reflect the new ringtone display
                    // name.
                    String name = ringtone.getTitle(preference.getContext());
                    preference.setSummary(name);
                }
            }

        } else {
            // For all other preferences, set the summary to the value's
            // simple string representation.
            preference.setSummary(stringValue);
        }

        return true;
    }
};

/**
 * Binds a preference's summary to its value. More specifically, when the
 * preference's value is changed, its summary (line of text below the
 * preference title) is updated to reflect the value. The summary is also
 * immediately updated upon calling this method. The exact display format is
 * dependent on the type of preference.
 *
 * @see #sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener
 */
private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
    // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);

    // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
    // current value.
    sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
            PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                    .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
}

boolean mAttachedFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mAttachedFragment = false;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

/**
 * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
 */
private void setupActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
    setTitle(getString(R.string.activity_settings));
}

@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    mAttachedFragment = true;
    super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //if we didn't attach a fragment, go ahead and apply the layout
    if (!mAttachedFragment) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);
        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // handle arrow click here
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    int recreateCounter = App.getRecreateUICounter();
    if (recreateCounter == 2){
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }

    if (recreateCounter > 1) {
        App.decreaseRecreateUICounter();
        Log.v("SETTINGS", "Decreasing! " + App.getRecreateUICounter());
    }
}

/**
 * This method stops fragment injection in malicious applications.
 * Make sure to deny any unknown fragments here.
 */
protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
    return PreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || GeneralPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || NotificationPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || PrivacyAndSecurityFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
            || ChatBackgroundsFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionEstablished() {

}

@Override
public void onConnectFailed() {

}

@Override
public void onAuthFailed() {

}

/**
 * This fragment shows general preferences only. It is used when the
 * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends AppCompatPreferenceFragment {

    private Context context;
    private PreferenceScreen languageListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        context = getActivity();

        //Enter button is send
        SwitchPreference enterIsSend = (SwitchPreference)findPreference("enter_is_send_key");
        enterIsSend.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                putPref("enter_is_send_key" , newValue, context);
                return true;
            }
        });

        // Delete all chats listening
        Preference deleteAllChats = findPreference("delete_all_chats_key");
        deleteAllChats.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                builder.setMessage(R.string.delete_all_chats_warning);

                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.contact_confirm, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        DatabaseController db = DatabaseController.getInstance(context);
                        db.openDatabase();
                        // Delete all messages in the message table
                        ChatMessage.clearAllMessagesForAllUsers(db);

                        // Delete all chat backgrounds
                        ChatBackground.clearAllBackgroundsForAllUsers(db);

                        // Set all active contacts as inactive
                        ContactData.clearAllActiveContacts(db);

                        db.close();
                    }

                });


                builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.contact_cancel, null);
                builder.show();
                return true;
            }
        });

        // Clear all chats listening
        Preference clearAllChats = findPreference("clear_all_chats_key");
        clearAllChats.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setMessage(R.string.clear_all_chats_warning);

                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.contact_confirm, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        DatabaseController db = DatabaseController.getInstance(context);
                        db.openDatabase();
                        // Delete all messages in the message table
                        ChatMessage.clearAllMessagesForAllUsers(db);

                        // Delete all chat backgrounds
                        ChatBackground.clearAllBackgroundsForAllUsers(db);
                        db.close();
                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.contact_cancel, null);
                builder.show();
                return true;
            }
        });

        //Number picker listening
        final NumberPickerFragment numberPicker =
                (NumberPickerFragment) findPreference("message_text_size_key");

        numberPicker.setSummary(Integer.toString(numberPicker.getValue()));

        numberPicker.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                numberPicker.setSummary(newValue.toString());
                return true;
            }
        });

        //Language setting
        languageListener = (PreferenceScreen) findPreference("UI_LOCALE");
        languageListener.setSummary(LocaleHelper.getLanguage(getPrefString("UI_LOCALE", context)));
        languageListener.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), UILanguageActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_EDIT_LANGUAGE);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == RESULT_EDIT_LANGUAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data.getBooleanExtra("new_UI_language", false)) {
                Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                getActivity().finish();
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This fragment shows notification preferences only. It is used when the
 * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class NotificationPreferenceFragment extends AppCompatPreferenceFragment {
    private Context context;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notification);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        context = getActivity();

        //Notification tone is listening
        RingtonePreference ringtonePreference = (RingtonePreference)findPreference("notifications_new_message_key");
        ringtonePreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                putPref("notifications_new_message_key", newValue, context);
                return true;
            }
        });

        //Vibrate swtich is listening
        SwitchPreference vibrateSwitch = (SwitchPreference)findPreference("new_message_vibrate_key");
        vibrateSwitch.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                putPref("new_message_vibrate_key", newValue, context);
                return true;
            }
        });

        //LED color is listening
        ListPreference ledColor = (ListPreference)findPreference("led_color_key");
        ledColor.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                putPref("led_color_key", newValue, context);
                return true;
            }
        });

        ListPreference priority = (ListPreference)findPreference("popup_priority_key");
        priority.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                putPref("popup_priority_key", newValue , context);
                return true;
            }
        });

        // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
        // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
        // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
        // guidelines.
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("notifications_new_message_key"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("led_color_key"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("popup_priority_key"));

    }

}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class PrivacyAndSecurityFragment extends AppCompatPreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_privacy);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        SwitchPreference readStatues = (SwitchPreference)findPreference("show_read_statues_key");
        readStatues.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                putPref("show_read_statues_key", newValue , getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                return true;
            }
        });

        ListPreference privacy = (ListPreference)findPreference("button_show_profile_pic_key");
        int index = privacy.findIndexOfValue(getPrefString("button_show_profile_pic_key", getActivity()));
        privacy.setSummary(index >= 0
                        ? privacy.getEntries()[index]
                        : null);

        privacy.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
                int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(newValue.toString());

                preference.setSummary(
                        index >= 0
                                ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                                : null);

                if (!getPrefString("button_show_profile_pic_key", getActivity()).equals(newValue.toString())) {
                    ProfileHelper.sendProfileToServer(false, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                }
                return true;
            }
        });


        // Delete all chats listening
        Preference deleteAccount = findPreference("delete_account_key");
        deleteAccount.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                builder.setMessage(R.string.delete_account_warning);

                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.contact_confirm, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // Set init state
                        /*SharedPrefManager.setAccountState(States.ACC_INIT);

                        // Send delete account iq stanza to message server
                        SocketConnection socketConnection = ((App)getActivity().getApplicationContext()).getSocketConnection();

                        if (socketConnection != null) {
                            socketConnection.sendDeleteAccount();
                        }*/
                    }

                });


                builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.contact_cancel, null);
                builder.show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class ChatBackgroundsFragment extends AppCompatPreferenceFragment {
    private Context context;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = getActivity();
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_chat_backgrounds);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        //Switches values changes and listening
        final SwitchPreference retainChatSwitch = (SwitchPreference)findPreference("retain_chat_key");
        final ListPreference backgroundQaulWifi = (ListPreference)findPreference("backgrounds_wifi_quality_key");
        final ListPreference backgroundQaulMobileData = (ListPreference)findPreference("backgrounds_mobile_data_quality_key");
        final ListPreference backgroundQaulRoaming = (ListPreference)findPreference("backgrounds_roaming_quality_key");
        final ListPreference backgroundChangingModelRetain = (ListPreference)findPreference("background_changing_retain_chat_key");

        retainChatSwitch.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

                    putPref("retain_chat_key", newValue, context);
                    return true;
            }
        });


        backgroundChangingModelRetain.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                return true;
            }
        });


        backgroundQaulWifi.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                return true;
            }
        });

        backgroundQaulMobileData.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                return true;
            }
        });

        backgroundQaulRoaming.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                return true;
            }
        });

        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("backgrounds_wifi_quality_key"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("backgrounds_mobile_data_quality_key"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("backgrounds_roaming_quality_key"));
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("background_changing_retain_chat_key"));


    }
}

public static void putPref(String key, Object value, Context context) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    if (value instanceof String) {
        editor.putString(key, (String)value);
    } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
        editor.putBoolean(key, (Boolean) value);
    } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
        editor.putInt(key, (Integer) value);
    }

    editor.apply();
}


public static String getPrefString(String key, Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return preferences.getString(key, null);
}

public static boolean getPrefBool(String key, Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return preferences.getBoolean(key, false);
}

public static int getPrefInteger(String key, Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return preferences.getInt(key, 0);
}

public static void setDefaultSettings(Context context) {
    // General
    putPref("enter_is_send_key", false, context);
    putPref("message_text_size_key", context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.number_default_value), context);

    // Background settings
    putPref("retain_chat_key", true, context);
    putPref("background_changing_retain_chat_key", context.getString(R.string.medium_speed_change), context);
    putPref("backgrounds_wifi_quality_key", context.getString(R.string.background_quality_high_value), context);
    putPref("backgrounds_mobile_data_quality_key", context.getString(R.string.background_quality_low_value), context);
    putPref("backgrounds_roaming_quality_key", context.getString(R.string.background_quality_low_value), context);

    // Privacy settings
    putPref("show_read_statues_key", true, context);
    putPref("button_show_profile_pic_key", context.getString(R.string.show_profile_pic_my_contacts_value), context);

    // Notifications
    putPref("mute_chat_key", true, context);
    putPref("notifications_new_message_key", "content://settings/system/notification_sound", context);
    putPref("new_message_vibrate_key", false, context);
    putPref("led_color_key", context.getString(R.string.led_color_cyan_value), context);
    putPref("popup_priority_key", String.valueOf(0), context);
}

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleContextWrapper.wrap(newBase, SharedPrefManager.getUILocale()));
}
```

}

Update:
I found out These two lines for setting up the settings layout and toolbar in the OnPostCreate function makes the settings crash. I tried it on OnCreate but still got the same problem. More detailed, setContentView makes the main problem and only in Oreo!!!

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);
setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
```

Comment: line number of error ?

Comment: No line error is mentioned in the code. It's an UncaughtException from my General preferences: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x102036d (android:id/prefs) for fragment GeneralPreferenceFragment{bc293e5 #0 id=0x102036d}

Comment: Same issue, did you get it resolved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Cause of Issue

This issue arises because the PreferenceActivity’s startPreferencePanel method assumes to have a layout with id ***com.android.internal.R.id.prefs (android:id/prefs)***. It tries to replace this layout with the an instance of your PreferenceFragment. Since you have used a custom layout using setCotentView, this ***com.android.internal.R.id.prefs (android:id/prefs)*** is not found and it crashes.

When we do not set our custom layout, the PreferenceActivity uses the layout [preference_list_content.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-8.0.0_r1/core/res/res/layout/preference_list_content.xml). This layout xml file has the required id.

## Why does this happens only on Android Oreo and above for you?

The reason is that prior to Android Oreo, the PreferenceActivity could attach the new Fragment in another manner (See startWithFragment call under startPreferencePanel method).

Android 7.1.2 : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-7.1.2_r36/core/java/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.java#1356

```
public void startPreferencePanel(String fragmentClass, Bundle args, @StringRes int titleRes,
        CharSequence titleText, Fragment resultTo, int resultRequestCode) {
    if (mSinglePane) {
        startWithFragment(fragmentClass, args, resultTo, resultRequestCode, titleRes, 0);
    } else {
        Fragment f = Fragment.instantiate(this, fragmentClass, args);
        if (resultTo != null) {
            f.setTargetFragment(resultTo, resultRequestCode);
        }
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(com.android.internal.R.id.prefs, f);
        if (titleRes != 0) {
            transaction.setBreadCrumbTitle(titleRes);
        } else if (titleText != null) {
            transaction.setBreadCrumbTitle(titleText);
        }
        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        transaction.addToBackStack(BACK_STACK_PREFS);
        transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

Android 8.0.0 : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-8.0.0_r1/core/java/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.java#1393

```
public void startPreferencePanel(String fragmentClass, Bundle args, @StringRes int titleRes,
        CharSequence titleText, Fragment resultTo, int resultRequestCode) {
    Fragment f = Fragment.instantiate(this, fragmentClass, args);
    if (resultTo != null) {
        f.setTargetFragment(resultTo, resultRequestCode);
    }
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(com.android.internal.R.id.prefs, f);
    if (titleRes != 0) {
        transaction.setBreadCrumbTitle(titleRes);
    } else if (titleText != null) {
        transaction.setBreadCrumbTitle(titleText);
    }
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    transaction.addToBackStack(BACK_STACK_PREFS);
    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

## Solution

Google recommends using a normal Activity instead of PreferenceActivity if you are targeting Honeycomb and higher and attaching a PreferenceFragment to it.

You can use the method `addPreferencesFromResource` to display your PreferenceScreen in PreferenceFragment.

However, this will break UI flow. Clicking on this PreferenceFragment will not do anything. To fix this you just have to implement `PreferenceFragment.OnPreferenceStartFragmentCallback` in your Activity and replace the currently added fragment(s) with the new fragment.

For a much detailed explanation, please refer to my blog post **[Fixing IllegalArgumentException: No view found when using PreferenceActivity](https://medium.com/@ahashmi06/fixing-illegalargumentexception-no-view-found-when-using-preferenceactivity-83a099634ecd)**.