# Shared preferences gets deleted in OREO

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I save the preferences while logging in and it gets saved properly. And after again running the app from android studio clears the app sharedpreferences.
Please find the code below :

```
public static String getStringValue(Context context, String key) {
        if (null != context && null != key) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            return sharedPref.getString(key, (String)null);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void putStringValue(Context context, String key, String value) {
        if (null != context && null != key) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString(key, value);
            editor.apply();
        }

    }
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you show the code which concerns the sharedpreferences?

Comment: @LieForBananas please check the updated code

Comment: You have an interesting way of writing `if` statements. Also, I don't know why you cast `null` to `String` and not just put `null`. Judging from this code it looks like preferences should be saved. Is that the only place you use `SharedPreferences` no other place? You never call `clear()`?

Comment: No i never call clear. The case is only visible for my OREO users and not lower than that.

Comment: Any updates ?? @LieForBananas

Comment: When you don't mention a user with `@` he/she doesn't get notified. I can't help you further because the code above is right. If you are using PreferenceActivity check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910258/oreo-issue-with-settings-preferences-in-the-app) post, I upvoted your question, hope it will help you to get answers.

Comment: @LieForBananas no i am not using any PreferenceActivity. Anyways thanks for the support. Will post here if i find any solution.

Comment: No problem, good luck!